# What does it mean a string is lexicographically greater than another string?

Tags: java, string

I have two strings in java:

```
s1 = "-7ff9";
s2 = "-7ff9";
```

I get the s2 string from a response from a server. Instead string s1 is a value of a parameter. 
When I ask :

```
if(s1.equals(s2)){ System.out.println("YES");}
else System.out.println("NO");
```

I get the response **NO**.

I then compared the to strings:

```
System.out.println(s1.compareTo(s2));
```

I get an  **19** output which means " string s1 is lexicographically greater than the string argument s2"

I just don't know how to solve this ...

Comment: There is something else. Those two strings are equal, so there is one which is not what you think it is

Comment: Your two strings are not "-7ff9" , no matter how much you think they are. If both s1 and s2 actually was "-7ff9" , they would indeed be equal. Try to figure out what their actual values are.

Comment: Are you sure that s2 is a String?

Comment: Add this, to your code and show us the result -         `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s1.getBytes()));` `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s2.getBytes()));`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved my problem using :

```
if (s1.contentEquals(s2))
```

Comment: Please add output of `getBytes()` to show the difference.

Comment: I just don't get anything when I use System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s1.getBytes()));

Comment: This is not possible if your strings are `"-7ff9"` (as you wrote), I have `[45, 55, 102, 102, 57]` as the result... Are you printing it before the `if` statement?

Comment: yes i printed it before if

Comment: ok then and `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s2.getBytes()));` is? But even for empty String (`""`) it should print `[]`...

Answer (score 8):

"Lexographically greater" means it would appear *after* the other String if sorted by the unicode value of its (left-justified) characters.

Just a guess, but it's the only reason I can think of that explains what you're seeing: The two minus signs are not in fact the same character. There are several characters that look (are printed) similar, but they are different unicode characters.

See [this link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm) for the many characters that are considered a "dash".

Comment: That was my thoughts too.

Comment: good idea, `String.getBytes()` can help here ;-)

Answer (score -4):

You are comparing references, not teh contents. .equals() tests for value equality. For ignoring case, use equalsIgnoreCase(). String's compareTo Compares two strings lexicographically, means as if in a disctionary comparison

Comment: He is correctly doing s1.equals(s2), not s1 == s2